# Could not resolve project :react-native-camera

Tags: android, react-native

I'm having this error for days and couldn't find answer.

After running react-native run-android got this error message:

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-camera: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Android studio updated to newest grade version.

**UPDATE**

Apparently after adding new modules and using npm install method react-native-camera has been deleted for some reason from node_modules directory

My solution was to copy node_modules (react-native-camera) file every time this error occurred to node_modules directory

Comment: which version of react native you are using

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1

Comment: react-native: 0.55.4

Comment: after installation did you link react-native-camera ?

Comment: react-native-camera is linked

Comment: But I'm using older version of react-native-camera
import com.lwansbrough.RCTCamera.RCTCameraPackage;